# Heroku buidpack name longer than 30 letters?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy a buildpack to heroku which I have renamed to get under 30 letters, but I'm still getting :

```
/f/envs/r1/driver1 (master)
$ heroku create --stack cedar https://github.com/kc1/hero-bpack-py-phant.git          
 !    Name must start with a letter and can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes.
 !    Name is too long (maximum is 30 characters)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI here is determining your application name to be `https://github.com/kc1/hero-bpack-py-phant.git`

What in fact you need to do is:

```
heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/kc1/hero-bpack-py-phant.git <APPNAMEHERE>
```

note `--buildpack` and `<APPNAMEHERE>` at the end of the command.